# Twitter command line for Windows

Tags: windows, twitter, command, message, send

I'm looking for a "Text sender" twitter command-line for Windows, but with only a unique .exe (and without .net dependencies).  Not python, perl, and others scripts.
I test the "twt.exe", but they crash in Windows x64.
Any help is welcome.
Thank you

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?

Comment: I'm trying post at twitter status from my automated system.  Like if they crash, I post "crash", if they works fine, I post "fine", etc...